# Updating selected row using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update specific row in tables using button tag .But it is updating last inserted row only and not the selected button tag.

Model

```
 public function title_d($data,$title_id)
{
      
        $this->db->where('title_id',$title_id);
        $this->db->update('experience',$data);
}
```

view

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/portfolio/user/title">
  
      <?php
         foreach($experience->result() as $values1)  {
        ?>
        <section class="row">
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-5" style="background: #fff; width: 30%; height: 250px;">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values1->title_id;?>" name="title_id" hidden />
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values1->title;?>" class="form-control place" name="title" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;  border: 1px solid;">
        </section>  
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-4" style="background: #fff; width: 23%;height: 250px;">
        <h5>Write What you know</h5>
        <textarea  style=" height: 150px; width: 180px;" name="write">
        <?php echo $values1->write;?>
        </textarea>
        </section>
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-5" style="background: #fff; width: 25%; height: 250px;  ">
        <h5>update your details</h5>
        <button type="submit"  value="<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?>" style="background:#1C8ACA; height: 40px; " class="btn btn-primary">Update<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?></button>
        <button type="submit"  value="<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?>"style="background:#ff0000;  height: 40px; " class="btn btn-danger">Delete<?php echo $values1->title_id;?></button>
        </section>
        </section>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</form>
```

controller:

```
Class User extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $user_id = 1;
    $data['admin'] = $this->User_model->admin_data($user_id);
    $data['images'] = $this->User_model->get_images($user_id);
    $data['names'] = $this->User_model->get_name();
    $data['intro'] = $this->User_model->get_intro();
    $data['experience'] = $this->User_model->get_title();
    $data['contact'] = $this->User_model->get_contact();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('Home',$data);
 }
 public function title()
 {
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $title_id = $this->input->post('title_id');
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $write = $this->input->post('write');
    $data = array("title"=>$title,"write"=>$write);
    $this->User_model->title_d($data,$title_id);
    $this->User_model->delete_title($title_id,$data);
    redirect('/');
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please share the view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create your loop with the form inside, like:

```
<?php foreach($experience->result() as $values1) { ?>
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/portfolio/user/title">
        <section class="row">
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-5" style="background: #fff; width: 30%; height: 250px;">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values1->title_id;?>" name="title_id" hidden />
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values1->title;?>" class="form-control place" name="title" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;  border: 1px solid;">
        </section>  
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-4" style="background: #fff; width: 23%;height: 250px;">
        <h5>Write What you know</h5>
        <textarea  style=" height: 150px; width: 180px;" name="write">
        <?php echo $values1->write;?>
        </textarea>
        </section>
        <section class="border mt-5 m-auto p-5" style="background: #fff; width: 25%; height: 250px;  ">
        <h5>update your details</h5>
        <button type="submit"  value="<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?>" style="background:#1C8ACA; height: 40px; " class="btn btn-primary">Update<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?></button>
        <button type="submit"  value="<?php echo $values1->title_id; ?>"style="background:#ff0000;  height: 40px; " class="btn btn-danger">Delete<?php echo $values1->title_id;?></button>
        </section>
        </section>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Even that's also done but its not working.

Comment: Why do you update and delete just after in your controller?

Comment: yeah I removed delete and using just update